# Jquery click link to .show loader unless link has class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery function that .show() my "loading screen" by adding `.loader` class that wraps the entire `body` when I click on any links. But there are some links I don't want to show the .loader class. If I add a class to some of the `a` tags like `no-load`, can I use jquery's `hasClass` to not run the `.loader` function? Does anyone know how to do it?

Here's my code that works for all my links:

```
$(function () {
$('ul.menu a, .logo-img a').click(function () {
  $('.loader').show();
  });
});
```

Comment: just add the if  `if(!$(this).hasClass('no-load')) { $('.loader').show(); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [`.not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not/) like:

```
$('ul.menu a, .logo-img a').not('.no-load').click(function () {
```